# Using Lambda to get image from S3 returns a white box in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get my image from S3 bucket and return it. Here's the code:

```
import base64
import boto3
import json
import random

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    number = random.randint(0,1)
    if number == 1:
        response = s3.get_object(
            Bucket='bucket-name',
            Key='image.png',
        )
        image = response['Body'].read()
        return {
            'headers': { "Content-Type": "image/png" },
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': base64.b64encode(image).decode('utf-8'),
            'isBase64Encoded': True
        }
    else:
        return {
            'headers': { "Content-type": "text/html" },
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': "<h1>This is text</h1>",
        }
```

When I hit my endpoint, an image of a tiny white box is returned. I know `image.png` exists in my bucket, and when I use the web GUI to open it in my browser, the image is loaded properly. What am I exactly doing wrong here? And in case it matters, here's how I'm uploading the image to S3 (from another Lambda):

```
...

# Prepare image for S3
buffer = io.BytesIO()
my_image.save(buffer, 'PNG')
buffer.seek(0) # Rewind pointer back to start
    
response = s3.put_object(
    Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key=f'{S3_KEY}{filename}.png',
    Body=buffer,
    ContentType='image/png',
)

...
```

In the above code, `my_image` is just an image I created using the `PIL` library.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How large is the image? Note that both API Gateway and AWS Lambda have payload size limits. Your code seems to be the [canonical example from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html) which I would assume works fine, so I suspect that you have configured something incorrectly, e.g. Lambda proxy integration.

Comment: @jarmod Around 100kb. Can I increase the payload size limits?

Comment: No, they are hard limits (10MB for API Gateway, 6MB for Lambda iirc) but 100KB, even base64-encoded, will be fine. You should use pre-signed URLs if you need larger (uploads or downloads).

Comment: Why do you base64.decode it? Your upload procedure does not involve any base64 encoding.

Comment: @Marcin How else would you return it? I was following a tutorial from AWS docs.

Comment: This lambda code works as-is for me.  If you manually upload the image using the CLI, does it work?

Comment: How did you setup your API gateway and how do you use the API gateway url to shown the image in the browser? Please update the question with all the details.

Comment: @AnonCoward It doesn't when I use the GUI to upload an image either. Does that work for you as is? Then I'm fairly certain it's an issue with the API configurations.

Comment: Yes, it works regardless of how I upload the image

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is how I do this:

Your lambda with corrected `body`:

```
import base64
import boto3
import json
import random

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    response = s3.get_object(
        Bucket='bucket-name',
        Key='image.png',
    )
    image = response['Body'].read()

    return {
        'headers': { "Content-Type": "image/png" },
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': base64.b64encode(image),
        'isBase64Encoded': True
    }
```

**API gateway settings**

[image]

**Integration Request**

[image]

Comment: API gateway setting was it for me. 